# html, jsp ,javascript

Tags: java, jsp

I have  three jsp `GetAllEmployee`,`EmployeeFindByid`,`EmployeeFindByName` ,now i have to code for `EmployeeFindById` ,`EmployeeFindByName` in one jsp,  i have provide the button for all three in home page (index.jsp) as the user click on `employeeFindbyid` new pop window open and demanding for id  after click on submit button output should be populate in index.jsp i have done with `GetAllEmployeei` m stucking in portion of `EmployeeFindByid`,`EmployeeFindByName` cause i have to write these in one jsp page as the user click on button one pop window should be open and taking the value then pop window should be closed automatically. I am not able to provide the conditon how to execute particular section of code of one jsp
this is my servlet package `com.nousinfo.tutorial`;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.service.model.bo.EmployeeBO;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.bo.EmployeeService;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.bo.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.exception.EmployeeServiceBOException;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.exception.EmployeeServiceException;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class GetEmployee
 */
public class GetEmployee extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeServiceImpl();

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GetEmployee() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String name = request.getParameter("findbyid");
        System.out.println(name);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
        try {

            if (request.getParameter("findbyid") != null) {

                request.setAttribute("EmployeeObject", findEmployees(Long
                        .parseLong(request.getParameter("findbyid"))));
                dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/employee.jsp");

            } else {
                request.setAttribute("employeeList", getAllEmployee());
                dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/winopen.jsp");
            }
            if (dispatcher != null)
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        } catch (EmployeeServiceBOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private List<EmployeeBO> getAllEmployee() throws EmployeeServiceBOException {
        return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }

    private EmployeeBO findEmployees(long id) throws EmployeeServiceBOException {

        return employeeService.getEmployee(id);
    }

    private List<EmployeeBO> findEmployees(String name)
            throws EmployeeServiceBOException {

        return employeeService.findEmployees(name);
    }
}
```

this is my index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"></link><title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="951" height="116" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="661" height="112" align="center" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><h2>Project Management </h2></td>
    <td width="266" height="112" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="../image/nous.jpg" alt="1" width="266" height="84" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>


    <table width="949" height="183" border="0" align="center">

      <tr>
        <td height="42" align="center" bgcolor="#3366FF"><strong>Find Employee </strong></td>
      </tr>

  <tr>

    <td height="43"><form id="form2"  method="post" action="/EmployeeWeb/GetEmployee">

       <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="button" value="GetAllEmployee"/>

    </form>    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
<td width="943" height="43">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="getEmployee By ID"
onClick="window.open('file.jsp','mywindow','width=500,height=200 align=center,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,menubar=yes' )" />
</td>
</tr>

    <tr>
    <td height="43">
    <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="button" value="Get Employee By Name"  onClick="window.open('winopen.jsp','mywindow','width=500,height=350,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,menubar=yes')"/>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my getAllEmployee.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@page  language="java" import="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.service.model.bo.*" %>
<%@page  language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
 <input name="employee id" value="">

    <table >
        <tr>
            <th>EmployeeNumber</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Address-1</th>
            <th>Address-2</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Pincode</th>
            <th>Mobile_Number</th>
            <th>Date_Of_Birth</th>

        </tr>
    <c:forEach var="employee" items="${employeeList}">
            <tr>
                <td>${employee.empNumber}</td>
                <td>${employee.firstName}</td>
                <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
                <td>${employee.title}</td>
                <td>${employee.address1}</td>
                <td>${employee.address2}</td>
                <td>${employee.city}</td>
                <td>${employee.state}</td>
                <td>${employee.pincode}</td>
                <td>${employee.mobileNUmber}</td>
                <td>${employee.dateOfBirth}</td>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ubercooluk i m not not finding any button or check to accept how to do it can u plz tell me

Comment: There is a tick symbol near to the answers of your question..

Comment: @ubercooluk can you plz give the solution of my question